# Erro consulta JPA list

Tags: java, jpa, lista, gwt

Sou novo em `JPA` e estou tendo dificuldades na listagem de notas de um banco de dados. Quando consulto recebo o seguinte retorno.

> 11:00:32.247 [WARN] [opensig] Field 'private final
>   java.util.List nodes' will not be
>   serialized because it is final

> ```
> 2016-11-24 09:20:14 UtilServer [DEBUG] Sql gerado: SELECT DISTINCT t FROM FisNotaSaida t  WHERE ((UPPER(t.empEmpresa.empEntidade.empEntidadeNome1) LIKE :t_empEmpresa_empEntidade_empEntidadeNome1_152107899 OR UPPER(t.fisNotaStatus.fisNotaStatusDescricao) LIKE :t_fisNotaStatus_fisNotaStatusDescricao_1014348517 OR UPPER(t.fisNotaSaidaChave) LIKE :t_fisNotaSaidaChave_913259498 OR UPPER(t.fisNotaSaidaProtocolo) LIKE :t_fisNotaSaidaProtocolo_1795529018 OR UPPER(t.fisNotaSaidaXml) LIKE :t_fisNotaSaidaXml_2022449309 OR UPPER(t.danfe) LIKE :t_danfe_1873018079 OR UPPER(t.fisNotaSaidaProtocoloCancelado) LIKE :t_fisNotaSaidaProtocoloCancelado_526829418 OR UPPER(t.fisNotaSaidaXmlCancelado) LIKE :t_fisNotaSaidaXmlCancelado_71380022 OR UPPER(t.fisNotaSaidaProtocoloCarta) LIKE :t_fisNotaSaidaProtocoloCarta_1013287502 OR UPPER(t.fisNotaSaidaXmlCarta) LIKE :t_fisNotaSaidaXmlCarta_1503970636 OR UPPER(t.fisNotaSaidaRecibo) LIKE :t_fisNotaSaidaRecibo_1707101466 OR UPPER(t.fisNotaSaidaErro) LIKE :t_fisNotaSaidaErro_1809257062) AND ((t.fisNotaSaidaData >= :fisNotaSaidaData_934813336 AND t.fisNotaSaidaData < :fisNotaSaidaData_1627436408) AND t.empEmpresa.empEmpresaId = :empEmpresa_empEmpresaId_1271545887)) ORDER BY t.fisNotaSaidaData DESC
> 2016-11-24 09:20:14 UtilServer [ERROR] Erro ao selecionar
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
> Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT DISTINCT t FROM FisNotaSaida t  WHERE ((UPPER(t.empEmpresa.empEntidade.empEntidadeNome1) LIKE :t_empEmpresa_empEntidade_empEntidadeNome1_152107899 OR UPPER(t.fisNotaStatus.fisNotaStatusDescricao) LIKE :t_fisNotaStatus_fisNotaStatusDescricao_1014348517 OR UPPER(t.fisNotaSaidaChave) LIKE :t_fisNotaSaidaChave_913259498 OR UPPER(t.fisNotaSaidaProtocolo) LIKE :t_fisNotaSaidaProtocolo_1795529018 OR UPPER(t.fisNotaSaidaXml) LIKE :t_fisNotaSaidaXml_2022449309 OR UPPER(t.danfe) LIKE :t_danfe_1873018079 OR UPPER(t.fisNotaSaidaProtocoloCancelado) LIKE :t_fisNotaSaidaProtocoloCancelado_526829418 OR UPPER(t.fisNotaSaidaXmlCancelado) LIKE :t_fisNotaSaidaXmlCancelado_71380022 OR UPPER(t.fisNotaSaidaProtocoloCarta) LIKE :t_fisNotaSaidaProtocoloCarta_1013287502 OR UPPER(t.fisNotaSaidaXmlCarta) LIKE :t_fisNotaSaidaXmlCarta_1503970636 OR UPPER(t.fisNotaSaidaRecibo) LIKE :t_fisNotaSaidaRecibo_1707101466 OR UPPER(t.fisNotaSaidaErro) LIKE :t_fisNotaSaidaErro_1809257062) AND ((t.fisNotaSaidaData >= :fisNotaSaidaData_934813336 AND t.fisNotaSaidaData < :fisNotaSaidaData_1627436408) AND t.empEmpresa.empEmpresaId = :empEmpresa_empEmpresaId_1271545887)) ORDER BY t.fisNotaSaidaData DESC]. 
> [471, 478] The state field path 't.danfe' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
>     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1512)
>     at br.com.opensig.core.server.CoreServiceImpl.selecionar(CoreServiceImpl.java:90)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor142.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>     at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
>     at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:265)
>     at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:305)
>     at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
>     at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:202)
>     at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:180)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1465)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:68)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

Aqui está a classe completa:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fis_nota_saida")
@XmlRootElement(name = "EcfNotaEletronica")
public class FisNotaSaida extends Dados implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "fis_nota_saida_id")
    @XmlElement(name = "ecfNotaEletronicaId")
    private int fisNotaSaidaId;

    @Column(name = "fis_nota_saida_chave")
    @XmlElement(name = "ecfNotaEletronicaChave")
    private String fisNotaSaidaChave;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "fis_nota_saida_cadastro")
    @XmlTransient
    private Date fisNotaSaidaCadastro;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "fis_nota_saida_data")
    @XmlElement(name = "ecfNotaEletronicaData")
    private Date fisNotaSaidaData;

    @Column(name = "fis_nota_saida_numero")
    @XmlElement(name = "ecfNotaEletronicaNumero")
    private int fisNotaSaidaNumero;

    @Column(name = "fis_nota_saida_evento")
    @XmlElement(name = "ecfNotaEletronicaEvento")
    private int fisNotaSaidaEvento;

    @Column(name = "fis_nota_saida_protocolo")
    @XmlElement(name = "ecfNotaEletronicaProtocolo")
    private String fisNotaSaidaProtocolo;

    @Column(name = "fis_nota_saida_recibo")
    @XmlElement(name = "ecfNotaEletronicaRecibo")
    private String fisNotaSaidaRecibo;

    @Column(name = "fis_nota_saida_protocolo_cancelado")
    @XmlElement(name = "ecfNotaEletronicaProtocoloCancelado")
    private String fisNotaSaidaProtocoloCancelado;

    @Column(name = "fis_nota_saida_protocolo_carta")
    @XmlElement(name = "ecfNotaEletronicaProtocoloCarta")
    private String fisNotaSaidaProtocoloCarta;

    @Column(name = "fis_nota_saida_valor")
    @XmlElement(name = "ecfNotaEletronicaValor")
    private Double fisNotaSaidaValor;

    @Column(name = "fis_nota_saida_icms")
    @XmlElement(name = "ecfNotaEletronicaIcms")
    private Double fisNotaSaidaIcms;

    @Column(name = "fis_nota_saida_ipi")
    @XmlElement(name = "ecfNotaEletronicaIpi")
    private Double fisNotaSaidaIpi;

    @Column(name = "fis_nota_saida_pis")
    @XmlElement(name = "ecfNotaEletronicaPis")
    private Double fisNotaSaidaPis;

    @Column(name = "fis_nota_saida_cofins")
    @XmlElement(name = "ecfNotaEletronicaCofins")
    private Double fisNotaSaidaCofins;

    @Lob()
    @Column(name = "fis_nota_saida_xml")
    @XmlElement(name = "ecfNotaEletronicaXml")
    private String fisNotaSaidaXml;

    @Lob()
    @Column(name = "fis_nota_saida_xml_cancelado")
    @XmlElement(name = "ecfNotaEletronicaXmlCancelado")
    private String fisNotaSaidaXmlCancelado;

    @Lob()
    @Column(name = "fis_nota_saida_xml_carta")
    @XmlElement(name = "ecfNotaEletronicaXmlCarta")
    private String fisNotaSaidaXmlCarta;

    @Lob()
    @Column(name = "fis_nota_saida_erro")
    @XmlTransient
    private String fisNotaSaidaErro;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fis_nota_status_id")
    @XmlTransient
    private FisNotaStatus fisNotaStatus;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "emp_empresa_id")
    @XmlTransient
    private EmpEmpresa empEmpresa;

    @Transient
    private String ecfNotaEletronicaStatus;

    public FisNotaSaida() {
        this(0);
    }

    public FisNotaSaida(int fisNotaSaidaId) {
        super("pu_fiscal", "FisNotaSaida", "fisNotaSaidaId", "fisNotaSaidaData", EDirecao.DESC);
        this.fisNotaSaidaId = fisNotaSaidaId;
        setTipoLetra(ELetra.NORMAL);
    }

    public int getFisNotaSaidaId() {
        return this.fisNotaSaidaId;
    }

    public void setFisNotaSaidaId(int fisNotaSaidaId) {
        this.fisNotaSaidaId = fisNotaSaidaId;
    }

    public String getFisNotaSaidaChave() {
        return this.fisNotaSaidaChave;
    }

    public void setFisNotaSaidaChave(String fisNotaSaidaChave) {
        this.fisNotaSaidaChave = fisNotaSaidaChave;
    }

    public Date getFisNotaSaidaCadastro() {
        return fisNotaSaidaCadastro;
    }

    public void setFisNotaSaidaCadastro(Date fisNotaSaidaCadastro) {
        this.fisNotaSaidaCadastro = fisNotaSaidaCadastro;
    }

    public Date getFisNotaSaidaData() {
        return this.fisNotaSaidaData;
    }

    public void setFisNotaSaidaData(Date fisNotaSaidaData) {
        this.fisNotaSaidaData = fisNotaSaidaData;
    }

    public int getFisNotaSaidaNumero() {
        return this.fisNotaSaidaNumero;
    }

    public void setFisNotaSaidaNumero(int fisNotaSaidaNumero) {
        this.fisNotaSaidaNumero = fisNotaSaidaNumero;
    }

    public String getFisNotaSaidaProtocolo() {
        return this.fisNotaSaidaProtocolo;
    }

    public void setFisNotaSaidaProtocolo(String fisNotaSaidaProtocolo) {
        this.fisNotaSaidaProtocolo = fisNotaSaidaProtocolo;
    }

    public String getFisNotaSaidaRecibo() {
        return fisNotaSaidaRecibo;
    }

    public void setFisNotaSaidaRecibo(String fisNotaSaidaRecibo) {
        this.fisNotaSaidaRecibo = fisNotaSaidaRecibo;
    }

    public Double getFisNotaSaidaValor() {
        return this.fisNotaSaidaValor;
    }

    public void setFisNotaSaidaValor(Double fisNotaSaidaValor) {
        this.fisNotaSaidaValor = fisNotaSaidaValor;
    }

    public String getFisNotaSaidaXml() {
        return this.fisNotaSaidaXml;
    }

    public void setFisNotaSaidaXml(String fisNotaSaidaXml) {
        this.fisNotaSaidaXml = fisNotaSaidaXml;
    }

    public FisNotaStatus getFisNotaStatus() {
        return this.fisNotaStatus;
    }

    public void setFisNotaStatus(FisNotaStatus fisNotaStatus) {
        this.fisNotaStatus = fisNotaStatus;
    }

    public EmpEmpresa getEmpEmpresa() {
        return empEmpresa;
    }

    public void setEmpEmpresa(EmpEmpresa empEmpresa) {
        this.empEmpresa = empEmpresa;
    }

    public Number getId() {
        return fisNotaSaidaId;
    }

    public void setId(Number id) {
        fisNotaSaidaId = id.intValue();
    }

    public Double getFisNotaSaidaIcms() {
        return fisNotaSaidaIcms;
    }

    public void setFisNotaSaidaIcms(Double fisNotaSaidaIcms) {
        this.fisNotaSaidaIcms = fisNotaSaidaIcms;
    }

    public Double getFisNotaSaidaIpi() {
        return fisNotaSaidaIpi;
    }

    public void setFisNotaSaidaIpi(Double fisNotaSaidaIpi) {
        this.fisNotaSaidaIpi = fisNotaSaidaIpi;
    }

    public String getFisNotaSaidaErro() {
        return fisNotaSaidaErro;
    }

    public void setFisNotaSaidaErro(String fisNotaSaidaErro) {
        this.fisNotaSaidaErro = fisNotaSaidaErro;
    }

    public Double getFisNotaSaidaPis() {
        return fisNotaSaidaPis;
    }

    public void setFisNotaSaidaPis(Double fisNotaSaidaPis) {
        this.fisNotaSaidaPis = fisNotaSaidaPis;
    }

    public Double getFisNotaSaidaCofins() {
        return fisNotaSaidaCofins;
    }

    public void setFisNotaSaidaCofins(Double fisNotaSaidaCofins) {
        this.fisNotaSaidaCofins = fisNotaSaidaCofins;
    }

    public String getFisNotaSaidaProtocoloCancelado() {
        return fisNotaSaidaProtocoloCancelado;
    }

    public void setFisNotaSaidaProtocoloCancelado(String fisNotaSaidaProtocoloCancelado) {
        this.fisNotaSaidaProtocoloCancelado = fisNotaSaidaProtocoloCancelado;
    }

    public String getFisNotaSaidaXmlCancelado() {
        return fisNotaSaidaXmlCancelado;
    }

    public void setFisNotaSaidaXmlCancelado(String fisNotaSaidaXmlCancelado) {
        this.fisNotaSaidaXmlCancelado = fisNotaSaidaXmlCancelado;
    }

    public String getEcfNotaEletronicaStatus() {
        return ecfNotaEletronicaStatus;
    }

    public void setEcfNotaEletronicaStatus(String ecfNotaEletronicaStatus) {
        this.ecfNotaEletronicaStatus = ecfNotaEletronicaStatus;
    }

    public int getFisNotaSaidaEvento() {
        return fisNotaSaidaEvento;
    }

    public void setFisNotaSaidaEvento(int fisNotaSaidaEvento) {
        this.fisNotaSaidaEvento = fisNotaSaidaEvento;
    }

    public String getFisNotaSaidaProtocoloCarta() {
        return fisNotaSaidaProtocoloCarta;
    }

    public void setFisNotaSaidaProtocoloCarta(String fisNotaSaidaProtocoloCarta) {
        this.fisNotaSaidaProtocoloCarta = fisNotaSaidaProtocoloCarta;
    }

    public String getFisNotaSaidaXmlCarta() {
        return fisNotaSaidaXmlCarta;
    }

    public void setFisNotaSaidaXmlCarta(String fisNotaSaidaXmlCarta) {
        this.fisNotaSaidaXmlCarta = fisNotaSaidaXmlCarta;
    }

    public String[] toArray() {
        return new String[] { fisNotaSaidaId + "", empEmpresa.getEmpEmpresaId() + "", empEmpresa.getEmpEntidade().getEmpEntidadeNome1(), fisNotaStatus.getFisNotaStatusId() + " ",
                fisNotaStatus.getFisNotaStatusDescricao(), UtilClient.getDataGrid(fisNotaSaidaCadastro), fisNotaSaidaNumero + "", UtilClient.getDataGrid(fisNotaSaidaData),
                fisNotaSaidaValor.toString(), fisNotaSaidaChave, fisNotaSaidaIcms.toString(), fisNotaSaidaIpi.toString(), fisNotaSaidaPis.toString(), fisNotaSaidaCofins.toString(),
                fisNotaSaidaEvento + "", fisNotaSaidaProtocolo, "xml", "danfe", fisNotaSaidaProtocoloCancelado, "cancelada", fisNotaSaidaProtocoloCarta, "cc-e", fisNotaSaidaRecibo, "*" };
    }

    public Dados getObjeto(String campo) {
        if (campo.startsWith("fisNotaStatus")) {
            return new FisNotaStatus();
        } else if (campo.startsWith("empEmpresa")) {
            return new EmpEmpresa();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void anularDependencia() {
        fisNotaStatus = null;
        empEmpresa = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: ```The state field path 't.danfe' cannot be resolved to a valid type.```


Parece que o campo t.danfe não está escrito dessa forma no seu objeto.

Comment: @Sorack Veja isso: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5359/132 - Tive que refazer a sua edição.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Opa beleza, obrigado por me orientar sobre esse caso!

Comment: Wellinton, a classe `FisNotaSaida` tem um campo chamado `danfe`? Ou métodos `getDanfe()` e `setDanfe(...)`?

Comment: Não tem os gets e nem sets. Olhe só a classe que inseri na publicação.

Comment: @Wellinton Isso que você inseriu não é uma classe, é apenas um método. E esse método não cria consultas JPA e utiliza um monte de variáveis que você não diz o que são.

Comment: Verdade, mas é que o erro está ai. De qualquer forma, vou postar toda.

Comment: Olá, pode por favor colar a query que esta usando para fazer a consulta?